# Should folder names start with a period?

Tags: .net, naming-conventions, directory

Are there any guidelines or standards out there for folder names starting with a period? (e.g.:  .NET).  I have an installer that requires this to happen and right now we are using 'DotNET' instead of '.NET' for our folder names.

Thanks!

Comment: Requires *what* to happen? The more I read, the less I understand that question...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no such guidelines in the Windows world.

In unix/linux environments, any file or directory starting with a . is by convention a hidden file/directory.

Answer (score 5):

Folders that start with a period are perfectly fine. If you do any Mono development, however, keep in mind that in unix/linux/GNU, anything that has a period prefix is "hidden" by default.

Answer (score 3):

Historically filenames that start with a '.' character are hidden (Unix, Linux, Mac OS X). On Windows they can be device names. Generally best to avoid file or directory names that start with a '.' character.

Comment: I must admit, I'm stymied by your second sentence. Care to elaborate as to the dangers of device name clobbers? I was previously unaware there could ever be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

There are generally no issues with starting folder names with a period; however, unlike Unix and Linux environments these folders won't be hidden. To do that in Windows you need to set the System attribute on the folder.

Answer (score 1):

Watch out with this; although you can create them programatically, you can't create a file like this with Windows Explorer. Trying in Windows7 to rename a folder to ".net" it complained that I hadn't provided a filename. So this means users and developers might have trouble. It's probably not worth doing.

Microsoft install the framework in \windows\Microsoft.Net, so you might want to use that instead.

Comment: I'll admit I haven't adoped Windows 7 yet, but my command shell works just fine creating folders or files with a period. Admittedly, I have to use quotes... `mkdir ".NET"` ... but other than that, periods work just fine in the shell. Is this a new issue in Win7?

Comment: Ooo! That's interesting. Same on Windows XP - you're fine at the command line, but interactively in the Explorer shell you get a prompt "You must provide a filename".

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm using the command line as Randolpho has pointed out. I just wanted to make sure there wasn't de facto standard against starting a folder with a period in windows. Thanks!

Comment: DUH! I totally misread your post, @Steve. I went and pointed and clicked in Windows Explorer rather than the command shell and everything failed just as you described. Lesson Learned: parse the whole paragraph.